# How to know the input shape of a pytorch model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a list of 100 matrix with the shape `(20,48)` and I want to pass this matrix in pytorch.

This is the sample code

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

sample = torch.randn(100,20,48)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(20, 48, kernel_size=2)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)

net = Net()

for i in net.state_dict().keys():
    print(i)

for i in list(net.parameters()):
    print(i.shape)

#output

conv.weight
conv.bias

torch.Size([48, 20, 2])
torch.Size([48])
```

How to check that my the model takes an input of particular shape? In my case how can I confirm if my model input conv layer takes a matrix of the size (bs,20,48)?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake from my side. I didnt  think that properly but I have edited the question.

Comment: your model can take any matrix of shape `B-20-W` where `W>=2` (your kernel size).

Comment: Is my implementation correct? Sofar it doesn't throw any error!